# Parent class's function is called instead of sub-class's function while overriding function in javascript es-06

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm using javascript es-06 syntax in react-native for developing mobile apps. Here is my code:

> Super class:

```
export class ApiCallback {

    onResponse = (responseJson) => {
        console.log("super response")
    }

    onError = (error) => {
        console.log("super error")
    }

}
```

> Base class:

```
export class LoginCallback extends ApiCallback {

    onResponse(responseJson) {
        super.onResponse(responseJson)
        console.log(responseJson)
    }

    onError(error) {
        super.onError()
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

> Usage:

```
export class AuthenticationInteractor {

     doLogIn(loginCallback: LoginCallback) {

            fetch("http://google.com",
                {
                    method: "GET"
                })
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    loginCallback.onResponse(responseJson)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    loginCallback.onError(error)
                })

        }
}
```

and

```
new AuthenticationInteractor().doLogIn(new LoginCallback())
```

Here, instead of calling base class method (which is printing all resonse json in onResponse()), it's calling parent class's onResponse() function and printing

> "super response"

as result from base class's onResponse() function.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using assignment in the super class definition? This is likely the culprit. So instead of `onResponse = (responseJson) => {` use a plain `onResponse(responseJson) {`, the same way you define the subclass.

Comment: Thanks! It resolved my problem.

Comment: Well the first snippet is not valid ES6.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: you shouldn't use arrow functions as methods in classes.

```
export class ApiCallback {

    onResponse(responseJson) {
        console.log("super response")
    }

    onError(error) {
        console.log("super error")
    }

}
```

The complex answer is: when you declare class method as arrow function it won't be added to class prototype but will be added to object on initialization. In your case you add LoginCallback methods to prototype, but on initialization they were overwritten by methods from parent class.

So it's better to use classic functions as class methods always. But don't forget to bind context to them.

Comment: Given they are just assignments indeed, I would not call them "declarations".

Answer (score -1):

Please see below snippet, it will improve the understanding of function definition.
I think the `abc = function(){}`'s priority is bigger than `function abc(){}`.

So to replace the function in derived class you have to define the function in same way.

So in your case use

> onResponse(responseJson) { console.log("superresponse")}

on parent class will solve the problem.

```js
abc = function(){
  console.log("abc");
}
function abc(){
 console.log("def");
}

abc();

function def(){
  console.log("abc");
}
function def(){
 console.log("def");
}

def();

var ghi =function(){
  console.log("abc");
}
var ghi = function(){
 console.log("def");
}

ghi();
```

Comment: There is no `var` in the OPs code. The mechanisms of classes differ a lot.

Comment: I think in deep level, it will be same